# I'm facing LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Tags: python-3.x, trilateration, uwb

I have been trying to do trilateration using 3 anchor coordinates and range in centimeters from the node.

```
import numpy as np

# Define the coordinates of the anchor points
anchor1 = np.array([0.000,3.610,1.901])
anchor2 = np.array([4.405, 8.605,1.901])
anchor3 = np.array([4.377, 0.000, 1.887])

# Define the distances from the tag to each anchor point
d1 = 376
d2 = 460
d3 = 476

A = np.array([[-2*(anchor1[0] - anchor3[0]), -2*(anchor1[1] - anchor3[1]), -2*(anchor1[2] - anchor3[2])],
              [-2*(anchor2[0] - anchor3[0]), -2*(anchor2[1] - anchor3[1]), -2*(anchor2[2] - anchor3[2])],
              [(d1**2 - d3**2) - (anchor1[0]**2 - anchor3[0]**2) - (anchor1[1]**2 - anchor3[1]**2) - (anchor1[2]**2 - anchor3[2]**2)],
              [(d2**2 - d3**2) - (anchor2[0]**2 - anchor3[0]**2) - (anchor2[1]**2 - anchor3[1]**2) - (anchor2[2]**2 - anchor3[2]**2)]])

b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]])
b = np.transpose(b)

# Solve the system of equations to find the coordinates of the tag
x, y, z = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
tag_position = np.array([x, y, z])
```

I tried to reshape A:
`A = np.reshape(A, (4, 3))`
but i'm not able to reshape it because the array content is 4.